# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "categories" does not exist : ALTER TABLE "posts"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I have no idea how to solve it in my heroku migartion.
I tried to `db:reset` or 'heroku apps:destroy' and recreation.

1. This is the problem I confront whenever I try to execute `heroku run rails db:migrate`

   ```html
   rake aborted!
   StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "categories" does not exist
   : ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_9b1b26f040"
   FOREIGN KEY ("category_id")
     REFERENCES "categories" ("id")
   ```
2. in `schema.rb`

```html
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_05_17_111322) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.boolean "display_in_navbar", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "good"
    t.text "bad"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "impressions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "impressionable_type"
    t.integer "impressionable_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "controller_name"
    t.string "action_name"
    t.string "view_name"
    t.string "request_hash"
    t.string "ip_address"
    t.string "session_hash"
    t.text "message"
    t.text "referrer"
    t.text "params"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["controller_name", "action_name", "ip_address"], name: "controlleraction_ip_index"
    t.index ["controller_name", "action_name", "request_hash"], name: "controlleraction_request_index"
    t.index ["controller_name", "action_name", "session_hash"], name: "controlleraction_session_index"
    t.index ["impressionable_type", "impressionable_id", "ip_address"], name: "poly_ip_index"
    t.index ["impressionable_type", "impressionable_id", "params"], name: "poly_params_request_index"
    t.index ["impressionable_type", "impressionable_id", "request_hash"], name: "poly_request_index"
    t.index ["impressionable_type", "impressionable_id", "session_hash"], name: "poly_session_index"
    t.index ["impressionable_type", "message", "impressionable_id"], name: "impressionable_type_message_index"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_impressions_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "user_email"
    t.string "user_nickname"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.string "price"
    t.string "volume"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_posts_on_category_id"
  end

  create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.bigint "resource_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_roles_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "taggings", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "tag_id"
    t.string "taggable_type"
    t.integer "taggable_id"
    t.string "tagger_type"
    t.integer "tagger_id"
    t.string "context", limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.index ["context"], name: "index_taggings_on_context"
    t.index ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
    t.index ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "taggings_taggable_context_idx"
    t.index ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "tagger_id", "context"], name: "taggings_idy"
    t.index ["taggable_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id"
    t.index ["taggable_type"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_type"
    t.index ["tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "index_taggings_on_tagger_id_and_tagger_type"
    t.index ["tagger_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tagger_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "nickname"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.string "name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "users_roles", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "role_id"
    t.index ["role_id"], name: "index_users_roles_on_role_id"
    t.index ["user_id", "role_id"], name: "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_users_roles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "votable_type"
    t.bigint "votable_id"
    t.string "voter_type"
    t.bigint "voter_id"
    t.boolean "vote_flag"
    t.string "vote_scope"
    t.integer "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
    t.index ["votable_type", "votable_id"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_type_and_votable_id"
    t.index ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"
    t.index ["voter_type", "voter_id"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_type_and_voter_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "active_storage_attachments", "active_storage_blobs", column: "blob_id"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "taggings", "tags"
end
```

3. in `model/post.rb`

```html
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  resourcify
  acts_as_votable
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many_attached :images

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true

  def thumbnail input
    return self.images[input].variant(resize: '300X300').processed
    # code
  end

  private
  def image_type
  #  if images.attached? == false
  #    errors.add(:images, "are missing!")
  #  end
     images.each do |image|
         if !image.content_type.in?(%('image/jpeg image/png image/jpg'))
           errors.add(:images, 'needs to be a JPEG or PNG')
         end
     end
  end

end
```

4. in `model/category.rb`

```html
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  resourcify
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

6. in `config/routes.rb`

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'colorfinder#index'
  get 'searches/result'
  get 'comments/create'
  get 'colorfinder/index'
  get '/tagged', to: "posts#tagged", as: :tagged
  authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
    begin
      mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
    rescue
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
  resources :categories do
    resources :posts
  end
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put "like", to:    "posts#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
      delete :delete_image_attachment
    end
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: What migrations do you have?

Comment: Bunch of it. If it is not enough, please tell me.
  1.class DeviseCreateUsers     2.class RolifyCreateRoles    3.class CreatePosts    4.class AddNicknameToUser     5.class AddAdminToUsers    6.class AddNameToUsers     7.class ActsAsVotableMigration    8.class CreateComments 
   9.class CreateActiveStorageTables    10.class AddCategoryToPosts     11.class CreateCategories      12.class AddPriceAndVolumeToPosts     13.class AddUserIdToCategories

Comment: and I used 'act as taggable' gem, either.

Comment: Probably some migration is referencing `categories` before it's been created

Comment: Your migrations will run in the order of their file names. Thats why rails prefaces the file name with a timestamp. Most likely whats happening here is that your migrations are in the wrong order so that you're adding the foreign key constraint before the table it references is created. You can reorder the migrations by renaming the files so that they run in the correct order.